# disable error.log for specific directory

Tags: apache-2.2

how to disable error reporting to error.log in Apache for a specific directory (phpmyadmin) ?

- in httpd.conf
- in .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

For the [errorlog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errorlog) there is no built in way to achieve this. You could use [log piping](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#piped) to do this by piping the log messages to something that will ignore messages containing some specified string.

Define a pipe to handle the error log

```
ErrorLog "|/usr/local/bin/httpd_errors >>/var/log/apache2/error.log"
```

The contents of the httpd_errors script can be as simple as

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

$|=1;

while (<STDIN>)
    {
     $ErrorMessage=$_;
     if ( $ErrorMssage !~ 'phpmyadmin' )
        {
         print $ErrorMessage;
        }
    }
```

This waits for messages to arrive on `stdin` and only prints them if they do not contain the string `phpmyadmin`.

If you want to ignore multiple error messages then

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
#unbuffer stdout
$|=1;
#add the strings to match below separated by |
$filter = 'phpmyadmin|setup.php';
while (<STDIN>)
    {
     $ErrorMessage=$_;
     if ( $ErrorMessage !~ m/($filter)/  )
        {
         print $ErrorMessage;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what then if I want to keep all error msgs, but pipe errors from one directory to a second error.log file?

Comment: Use an else statement and open then print to a different log file.

Comment: how do you set the pointer to another file?